# Pipeline input to executable with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pipelining

I need to execute the following command in PowerShell:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add site /in < c:\mywebsite.xml
```

I am trying to do it like this:

```
$appCmd = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"      

[String] $targetFilePath = $restoreFromDirectory + "config.xml"

$AllArgs = @('add', 'site', '/in')

& $appCmd $AllArgs | Get-Content $targetFilePath
```

But this is apperantly wrong since it gives me an error:

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
>   either because the command does not  take pipeline input or the input
>   and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take
>   pipeline  input.

Please assist on what is the correct alternative to the above mentioned script in PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell pipe takes input on the left, and passes it into the command on the right. In this case, you are passing the output of your command to `Get-Content`, which doesn't take an input parameter.

Change your call line so that the input flows from left to right:

```
Get-Content $targetFilePath | & $appCmd $AllArgs
```

See this [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11447598/935614) for an example.